# Crop and join two spatial data

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, r-sp

I have two dataset, the first one (df1) which has latitude and longitude and the second one (usa) is (sf, datafarme).

```
df1 = structure(list(Latitude = c(44.11, 45.78, 44.49, 46.87, 44.81, 
44.11, 44.45, 45.78, 44.79, 45.22, 47.3, 44.24, 44.33, 44.96, 
44.98, 44.73, 44.36, 45.14, 45.98, 46.59, 46.53, 44.48, 45.09, 
44.31, 45.79, 44.74, 45.02, 44.71, 44.55, 46.91, 44.58, 44.1, 
45.39, 44.84, 45.08, 46.16, 44.49, 44.31, 44.37, 44.36, 44.38, 
46.88, 46.21, 44.31, 44.7, 44.68), Longitude = c(-70.15, -87.08, 
-73.12, -68.03, -68.8, -70.15, -71.17, -87.08, -85.64, -67.26, 
-68.57, -73.49, -71.75, -72.16, -74.82, -73.44, -74.11, -87.6, 
-86.21, -87.4, -84.33, -83.33, -83.41, -85.39, -84.71, -84.69, 
-84.66, -85.64, -87.92, -67.99, -70.54, -70.17, -68.52, -68.72, 
-69.86, -67.82, -73.2, -69.68, -69.75, -69.74, -69.79, -68.02, 
-67.79, -69.68, -67.57, -67.64)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the second one is "usa" and the class is  `"sf" "data.frame"`

```
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
usa = filter(world,admin =="United States of America")
usa <- st_as_sf(maps::map("state", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE))
```

I want to subset data points staying within the polygons. I have created   temporary SpatialPointsDataFrame to exclude points in "df1" can be outside "usa", but I had this error:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'y' in selecting a method for function 'over': internal problem in as(): “sf” is(object, "data.frame") is TRUE, but the metadata asserts that the 'is' relation is FALSE"

How can I crop this two dataset:

Comment: I think you need to convert df1 to a class of sf as well.

Comment: That piece of code responsible for the error seems to be left out from question. You are also overwriting your Natural Earthh `usa`  object with the one from `maps` package, is this intentional?

Answer (score 1):

We can get the USA map and convert your data frame into an `sf` object as follows:

```r
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)

usa <- ne_countries(country = 'United States of America', 
                    scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

pts <- st_sf(geometry = st_sfc(st_multipoint(as.matrix(df1[2:1])), 
                               crs = st_crs(usa)))
```

We can plot a map of the continental US with the points overlaid as follows:

```r
usamap <- ggplot(usa) + geom_sf()

usamap + 
  geom_sf(data = pts) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-130, -60), ylim = c(20, 50))
```

[image]

We can then use `st_intersection` to get the points that intersect with our USA map, preserving them as an `sf` object:

```
filtered_pts <- st_intersection(pts, usa)
```

When we plot again, we will see that most of the points are preserved. A couple of points, which seem to be just off the coast of Maine, have been dropped:

```
usamap + 
  geom_sf(data = filtered_pts) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-130, -60), ylim = c(20, 50))
```

[image]